# $\kappa$-impediments (according to Shelah, Nash-Williams, Aharoni)

Tags: set-theory, graph-theory

Let $\Gamma = (M, W, K)$ be a bipartite graph, that is $M, W$ are sets and $K\subseteq M\times W$. If there is an injective function $f:M\to W$ such that $f\subseteq K$ we say $f$ is an *espousal* and $\Gamma$ is *espousable*. Moreover, $\Gamma$ is *critical*, if it is espousable, and every espousal is surjective.

For a bipartite graph $\Gamma = (M, W, K)$ and $A\subseteq M$ we set $W[A] = \{w \in W: (\exists m\in A): (m,w)\in K\}$. We also set $\Gamma|_A = (A, W[A], K\cap(A\times W[A])$

If $\kappa$ is a cardinal then we say that $\Gamma = (M, W, K)$ is a *$\kappa$-impediment* if there is a subset $A\subseteq M$  with $|A| = \kappa$ and $\Gamma|_{M\setminus A}$ is critical.

**Question**: Let $\Gamma = (M, W, K)$ be a 1-impediment and let $M$ be partitioned into $M_1\cup M_2$ and $W$ be partitioned into $W_1\cup W_2$. Is it true that at least one of $(M_i, W_i, K\cap (M_i\times W_i))$ contains a $\kappa$-impediment for $\kappa \leq \aleph_0$?